# approximate low rank matrix with weighted sum of rows

Tags: scipy, linear-algebra, svd, convex-hull, approximation

I'd like to approximate a given `n x m` matrix `A` with `n >> m` as a weighted sum `W` of some `k` rows `B` (ideally selected from `A`, but could also be arbitrary). The weights must sum up to 1 and need to be positive.

```
import numpy as np
n = 1000 # rows
m = 3 # columns
k = 2 # hidden rank
# create random matrix with rank k
A = np.random.rand(n, k).dot(np.random.rand(k, m))
# estimate hidden rank
u, s, vt = np.linalg.svd(A, full_matrices=False, compute_uv=True)
k_est = np.count_nonzero(~np.isclose(s, 0))
# truncate to k_est
B = np.diag(s[:k_est]) @ vt[..., :k_est, :]
W = u[..., :k_est]

# do some magic with B and W to come up with

assert np.all(W >= 0)
assert np.all(np.isclose(W.sum(1), 1))
assert np.all(np.isclose(A, W @ B))
```

I tried with SVD which is able to reproduce A by W @ B, but the weights are negative and don't sum up to 1.

From my gut feeling it seems like I'm searching for a convex hull of `A`, but with only `k_est` points.

Comment: If, as your example suggests the elements of A will all be non-negative, you might want to look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_matrix_factorization

Comment: That is close to what I try to achieve, thanks! In my case the values of `A` might also be negative, same for `B`. Does this simplify anything?